# Where can I get a program for "service call"?

Tags: ros, service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I used a command as below.

ros2 service call /set_message hello_world_msgs/srv/SetMessage \ '{message: "Hello service!"}'

I'd like to know how this program works.

But I couldn't find a program for "service call" in my computer and Internet.

So, I'd like to know where I can get the program.

Could someone tell me where can I get the program, please?

My environment is below.

Environment

OS: Ubuntu18.04.5 LTS

ROS2: Dashing Diademata

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/367916/where-can-i-get-a-program-for-%22service-call%22?/) by [snow](https://answers.ros.org/users/65776/snow/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-12-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `service call` part are just subcommands which are interpreted by the top-level `ros2` command. In this case the `ros2` command hands off execution to a python library defined by the `ros2service` package. You can see the source for this package here: https://github.com/ros2/ros2cli/tree/dashing/ros2service/ros2service Take a look inside verb/call.py to see what's running for the specific example in your question.

---

Originally posted by [jdlangs](https://answers.ros.org/users/2128/jdlangs/) with karma: 971 on 2020-12-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [snow](https://answers.ros.org/users/65776/snow/) on 2020-12-17**:
Thank you for your reply.
I had a look a program.
Does the program made by c++ exists?

**Comment by [jdlangs](https://answers.ros.org/users/2128/jdlangs/) on 2020-12-18**:
Check out the ros2 [examples](https://github.com/ros2/examples) and [demos](https://github.com/ros2/demos) repositories for sample programs in both C++ and Python. For example, a service calling example can be found [here](https://github.com/ros2/examples/blob/master/rclcpp/services/minimal_client/main.cpp).

**Comment by [snow](https://answers.ros.org/users/65776/snow/) on 2020-12-19**:
Thank you very much.
I appreciate your kindness.